# userdata in FormsAuthenticationTicket is secure?

Tags: asp.net, security

Every user have fixed data in profile like gender, role, ....
i want access them without query again to database.
what is the best solution?

1. session:ok but clear after some minutes.
2. FormsAuthenticationTicket user data: role may be hacked? i dont
       know.

   ```
   FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, member.UserName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(24), true, userData)
   ```

   3-any other ...

what is best solution?
best regard

i am using asp.net, c#

Answer (score 0):

You can put them in the ticket safely if you have configured the ticket to be encrypted. You can do this in web.config -

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms ....
   protection="All"
   .... >
  </forms>
</authentication>
```